# Volume of a prism derivation

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, 3d, area, volume

I was wondering if there was any way to formalise how I justify the formula for the volume of a prism.

For a given prism, its volume is given by the area of its cross section multiplied by the length of the prism.

I see this intuitively since the prism can be imagined to be made from infinitesimally many small slices of the cross-section throughout its length.

However, I am wondering if there is a way to formualise this?

Furthermore, [a cylinder is said to not be a prism](https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/prisms.html). However, the formula for its volume ($\pi r^2 \times h$) is identical  area of the cross section multiplied by the length. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: Well I would say that a cylinder is not a prism since the base of a prism is usually defined to be a polygon.

Comment: And yup, your intuition is on point - see [Cavalieri's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalieri%27s_principle).

Answer (score 0):

1. Convince yourself that volume of a box with sides $a,b,c$ is $abc$.
2. Then, think about having a square of size $1$ and area $1 \cdot 1$ turn into a box by extending it over the height $h$. The resulting box should have volume $1\cdot 1 \cdot h$, using (1) above.
3. Now think about rescaling the original square to fit the base of the prism. You have to scale in such a way that the resulting area becomes $A$, which is the area of the base. This scales by a factor of $A$, and hence the resulting volume should scale by the same factor, since the height is kept the same. So the final volume is $A\cdot h$.